# Faster inheritance through directly inlining code

Tags: c#, virtual-functions

I've come up with a way (not necessarily new) that replaces virtual tables for switch statements. This method allows inlining virtual functions at the cost of added memory.

Instead using a table look up, a sort of switch is used

```
switch (objecttype)
{
   case objectA: inlined virtual function call for foo from objectA; break;
   case objectB: inlined virtual function call for foo from objectB; break;
   case objectC: inlined virtual function call for foo from objectC; break;
   default: vtable call;
}
```

So instead of using a pointer lookup and making a call, a comparison is done. Inlining of code can be done for known classes.

To make this work well (avoid more than just the function call), objects would need to store their type. Types would need to be sequential.

For example:

```
class A
{
    ushort objectType; // internal id, say for class A it is 1000
    ushort objectInc; // internal. represents a sort of offset into the jump table
}

class B : A
{
    ushort objectInc; // one more than A's objectInc, has the same objectType
}

etc...
```

Then the switch statement can be made into an efficient jump table comparing on the `objectType` (make sure it's correct) and using `objectInc` and the code size to jump directly to the virtual function's code(instead of a bunch of comparisons).

As far as I can tell the downside to this scheme is more memory(larger classes and more inlined functions) and more compiler complexity but virtual functions can be directly inlined (the whole switch statement could be) so there are no wrapping calls. The only extra overhead should be just a few cycles extra due to a few comparisons and jumps (which is `O(1)`).

Does anyone have any useful comments on the performance of such a scheme and why it is not used (I'm sure I'm not the first to think of this)? I think it would be rather efficient except possibly cache invalidation due to the comparison but I think on average for base classes, it could be made within just a few cycles of a direct inlined method call.

By the way, the table could sort of be looked as a list of inlined virtual function calls for each object derivative.

Suppose we have the following:

```
class A
{
    void foo();
}

class B : A
{
    override void foo();
}

class C : A
{
    override void foo();
}


A a = new C();
a.foo();         // but calls fooWrap


/// internal
void fooWrap(A a)
{
    switch(a.Type)
    {
       case A: a.foo(); break; // A.foo() can be inlined here
       case B: b.foo(); break; // B.foo() can be inlined here
       case C: c.foo(); break; // C.foo() can be inlined here
       default: // use vtable lookup, a's type is not known at compile time
    }
}
```

(normally `fooWrap` would be the vtable lookup)

Now `fooWrap` could be inlined directly too in which case the cost of the call to `foo` is just the switch statement, which can be further optimized by using an efficient jump list.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume this is less efficient, as it needs comparisons or jump tables or whatever, while an indirect method call via vtable is fast: The offset within the vtable can be hard coded in the call, and indirect method calls are available as direct machine operations on most processors.

Furthermore, your approach would need a recompile each time another descendant is added to the system. Hence for systems like Java or .net that allow code to be loaded even from teh Internet while the application is running, a re-compilation of some code might be needed at runtime. To be honest, this is already done to undo some optimizations, but this would just e one more situation where you will have to do it.

And with regard to "objects would have to store their type": In .net and Java, this is the case already: Each object contains a pointer to its class definition, which among other information contains the vtable. Hence, there is only one vtable per class, not per object.

Comment: 1. The jump table would require only a comparison to verify the object is correct, which it can be assumed so, so no branch is generally taken. If the call is to a base class then it too will not require any jumps. 2. No recompiling would be needed. The default case resorts to using a vtable.

Comment: A comparison is normally more expensive (normally at least two machine instructions, and if the branch prediction of the cpu is wrong, a horrible performance effect) than an unconditional jump (which the indirect function call is to some extent).

Comment: @FrankPI Virtual are calls come at more of an expense than you are implying. You have to setup variables, push stuff, make the call, setup the stack, possibly fixup variables, return, etc... With a jump list there are no unconditional jumps except for the default. One can make an indirect jump which doesn't cause any prediction issues. One can also inline the functions as I have described which is the purpose, one can't do so with virtual functions.

Comment: @user2541029 "setup variables, push stuff, make the call, setup the stack, possibly fixup variables, return, etc." are all necessary for each function call, no matter if it is a indirect one coming from a virtual table) or a direct function call. This can onl be avoided by inlining or similar technologies like tail call optimization, but this again is independent of indirect or direct function call. In all situations where the compiler can determine the exact calling class and knows for sure that there will never be a descendant calling the method, inlining can be applied.

Comment: @FrankPI Um, for dynamic dispatch, inlining cannot be applied in general. We are not talking about specific cases as in those cases there is no need for dynamic dispatch. The fact is, a similar method to the one I have described is much more efficient and has been already implemented(see my answer).

Comment: @user2541029 How would your code behave if there is s new descendant class linked into the system dynamically that was not existing before? If this cannot be the case, then maybe avoiding vtables is a good approach. But in teh end, it is not the vtable approach that costs most of the time, it is the function call itself.

Comment: @FrankPI: As I showed in the code, if the object type is loaded in after compilation then it results in a standard vtable process. (This is the main difference between what I'm talking about and smart eiffel) For simple methods, such as property wrappers, the call is significant.

Answer (score 0):

Smart Eiffel uses a very similarly described technique with about 80% of virtual functions being inlined. There method does not allow for vtable dispatch as default which prevents dynamic linking so this may be a more appropriate idea for general purpose.

http://smarteiffel.loria.fr/papers/oopsla97.pdf